# What should I do with stackOverflow in compile error?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, compile, compilation-errors, error

I don't have port, but when I want to compile my code (even empty files),
I encounter this error:

```
Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

The code is:

```cpp
int LED_red=4;
int LED_yellow =2;
int green =0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(LED_red,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_yellow,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(LED_red,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED_yellow,LOW);
  digitalWrite(green ,LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(LED_yellow,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED_red,LOW);
  digitalWrite(green,LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(green,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED_yellow,LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_red,LOW);
  delay(5000);
}
```

```
Sketch uses 998 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

I want a hex address for cordinate this code with Proteus, but it doesn't compile and dosn't give me hex address.

Comment: I don't think that's an error.  It looks like the report regarding how much of the target processors resources you are using.  From the looks of it, you program is very small and will most certainly fit the target processor you have chosen.

Comment: Where is the Stack Overflow you mention in your question title? As others noted, your “error” is just a summary generated after successfully compiling your code and not an actual error.

Comment: What is the exact issue? As has been mentioned many times, **your code compiles fine** according to the output you’ve shown. You are not showing us any evidence of a problem. What does “I want hex address for cordinate this code with Proteus” mean? What hex address? Are you trying this with Proteus or with the Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 2):

> `Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.`
> `Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.`

This is not an error message. Rather, it's a message that results from a successful compile of your empty programme.

> `Sketch uses 998 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.`
> `Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.`

Neither is this an error message. Rather, it's a message that results from a successful compile of your more substantial programme.

To export the HEX file from the Arduino IDE for Proteus, go to:

- Menu bar -> Sketch -> Export compiled Binary

The short-cut is `Ctrl+Alt+S`.

You will find the .hex file in the same directory as your sketch.

Comment: Tanks a lot , your answer was so useful for me!

Comment: @dorsa, thanks. If it answers your question, be sure to accept it by clicking on the tick to left of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do.

What you are seeing is *not an error*. It is merely an informational message telling you how much of the available resources your sketch is using. Since it is using far less than the maximum available (as you would expect from an empty sketch) you have no problem.

You only need to worry about those figures when the "amount left" gets too small.

Comment: tanks a lot , but I want a hxe address for زcordinate this code with Proteus but it doesnt compile and dosent gove me hxe address ; can you tell me what should I do please?

Comment: @dorsa What code? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: int LED_red=4;   int LED_yellow =2; int green =0;
void setup() {
pinMode(LED_red,OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED_yellow,OUTPUT);
pinMode(green,OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_red,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_yellow,LOW);
     digitalWrite(green ,LOW);
       delay(5000);
       digitalWrite(LED_yellow,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(LED_red,LOW);
     digitalWrite(green,LOW);
    delay(5000);
        digitalWrite(green,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(LED_yellow,LOW);
             digitalWrite(LED_red,LOW);
        delay(5000);
}

Comment: @dorsa Please, don't post code in comments. Edit your question and provide *all* the information. Including what actual error you get when you try and compile.

Comment: Ok ,I do it ; do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: @dorsa There still is no error. What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is not an error.

Although your sketch is empty, there is Arduino framework code that gets created with it. This code actually calls your `setup()` and `loop()` functions so things operate as you would expect. It was designed this way to make it eaiser to get started.

Comment: thanks but I do not know what to do , can you help me again please and told me what to fo

Comment: @dorsa, you don’t have to do anything except upload your code to Arduino. Please follow a tutorial that explains the basics of how the Arduino IDE works, such as [this one](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoUno).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the processor settings from Tools-->Processor-->Atmega328P(Bootloader). It solved my problem.

Comment: Please explain how this solves the "problem". What was **your** error message?